# Flutter How to see document and data and does removing imported packages reduce size?

Tags: ios, flutter

APP document and data 3gb on IOS.
Just want to see what all comprises the document and data to be so huge.
Also if a widget has 15 imported packages, does removing the imported packages help with document and data size of app? Or does the majority of the size increase come from the package itself in the yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you cmeasure the app size with this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size), when you debug your app the weight is higher but when you compile the app the weight is less.
To check the size of the packages and more you can use the flag `--analyze-size` when you're going to build your app